# Pass variable to method name in PHP

Tags: php, variables, methods, call

I try to call method where part of name I want to in the variable. How can I do that, because code what I have for now not works ?

```
$actionName = 'Index';

// object creating...
$action = 'action' . $actionName();
$object->$action;
```

Error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function index() in ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call PHP methods in that way. You need to use [`call_user_func`](http://devdocs.io/php/function.call-user-func) to do it.

Example:

```
call_user_func([$object, 'action' . $actionName]/*,$param1, $param2, $param3*/)
//             ^ Callable                       ^ Optional parameters
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add () to variable method calls.

```
$actionName = 'Index';

$object->{"action" . $actionName}();
// or
$action = 'action' . $actionName;
$object->$action();
```

Example:

```
class test { function sts() { return "hey"; } }
$tst = new test;
$met = "sts";
echo $tst->$met();
```